# Independently reusing a declared strong property

Tags: cocoa, attributes, properties, instance, automatic-ref-counting

I created a class (MyClass) and need several instances of it, each will hold several timers, textfields and labels. Because of ARC, the target was getting deallocated when the timers were invalidated, but I sometimes invalidate them to restart them so I can't let them deallocate.  So I went to my AppDelegate (which is the class that creates the instances of MyClass) and declared MyClass as a strong property. `@property (strong) MyClass *myInstance;` This partially works the problem is that whenever I create another instance, the previous instance loses it's reference, and if I try to restart the NSTimer in an old instance, I get BAD ACCESS. If I restart the *last* timer there's no problem.

I believe that since myInstance is a property, whenever I make a new one the AppDelegate rewrites the old one, losing the old references. I need to either be able to keep the strong property but somehow make it work independently for each instance, or find another way to make myInstance a strong reference, without it having to be a property.

Comment: This design is pretty fragile anyway. NSTimers aren't meant to be invalidated and restarted. You should either have your callback ignore the ticks when they're meant to be "paused" or just create new ones.

Comment: @Chuck, what do you mean ignore the ticks? and how?

Comment: @Elbimio: Instead of invalidating the timer, let it fire. When it does, check whether you're paused and only do the thing that's meant to be periodic if you're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your instances in a Container like NSSet or NSArray.